# Importing Multi-value Custom Data

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, data-import

I'm trying to import custom fields from one civiCRM installation (on Drupal 7x) to another (WordPress, civi 5.52) using the "Import Multi-value Custom Data" tool. All my column names in the downloaded cvs file line up with custom fields in the new installation. Multi-Value Custom Data appears as a drop down list but the list is empty (there is nothing to select).
When I try to import the data an error claims "Multi-Value Custom Data is a required field".
What am I doing wrong?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You will need to select Multi-value custom data field to import. If the field is not populated then check the custom group if it is multi-value.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. The custom field template has a Multi-Select check box

Comment: and Active as well?